# Value of type 'UITableViewCell' has no member - static table Swift 3

Tags: uitableview, swift3

I want to create a header from a cell in a static UITableViewController.
The tableView controller contains 5 static cells.
 In the first cell I dropped 4 lables, created a  class `CustomHeader`.
In viewForHeaderInSection I get the error `Value of type 'UITableViewCell' has no member`. I know that if I used prototype cells, I would have been able to use `tableView.dequeueReusableCell`, but I don't know how to do it in static table.

```
import UIKit

class CustomHeader: UITableViewCell {

  @IBOutlet weak var dateHeaderlabel: UILabel!
  @IBOutlet weak var hourHeaderlabel: UILabel!
  @IBOutlet weak var totalHoursHeaderlabel: UILabel!
  @IBOutlet weak var priceHeaderlabel: UILabel!

override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
  }
}


class ManagedTable: UITableViewController,UITextFieldDelegate{

  override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {


    let index = tableView.indexPathsForVisibleRows?.first
    let  headerCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: index!)

// I get error on the next 4 lines Value of type 'UITableViewCell' has no    
     // member dataHeaderlabel...etc

    headerCell.dateHeaderlabel.text = StructS.headerDate
    headerCell.hourHeaderlabel.text = StructS.headerHours + " " + "-"
    headerCell.totalHoursHeaderlabel.text = String("\(Double(StructS.numberHours) + StructS.extrasHours) HOURS")
    headerCell.priceHeaderlabel.text = String("£\(StructS.price + StructS.totalExtras +  FullData.finalSuppliesAmount)")

    headerCell.backgroundColor =  UIColor(red: 230/255, green: 230/255, blue: 230/255, alpha: 1.0)
    return headerCell
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you try to cast headerCell to CustomHeader like `let  headerCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: index!) as! CustomHeader `

Comment: @AtaerCaner I tried, it's not working. You may give it a go in Xcode if you can.

Comment: Try `if let headerCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: index!) as? CustomHeader` and then put all the rest of the code for `headerCell` member variables inside that block.

Comment: @DanielLegler  Where do I get the index inside `tableView.cellForRow(at:_)`? Should I take it from my statement `let index = tableView.indexPathsForVisibleRows?.first    
    let  headerCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: index!)`

Comment: @DanielLegler It works. If you put your answer in the answer section, I'll give you an arrow. Many thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137698/discussion-between-bibscy-and-daniel-legler).

Comment: @DanielLegler. I have one more issue. In UIStoryBoard, in Attributes inspector in Header field, if I don't type anything my labels will not be populate with text. However, if I type an empty string the labels will be populated with text, but I will have an extra padding at the top of the table and I don't want that since I already have a header made from the first cell.  http://imgur.com/a/E80wI

Comment: @DanielLegler  There should be a property to enable me to set the height of tabelView's default header to 0, but I don't know the method..

Comment: I have set the height of the default header with this method and it works. `override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {  return 0.1}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `if let headerCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: index!) as? CustomHeader` and then put all the rest of the code for headerCell member variables inside that block. It looks like you weren't casting `headerCell` as your custom class.

Also make sure that `index` is being set as you expected